# Disabled DataGridRow is allowing keyboard edits

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a **DataGrid** with a single column (X). Depending on some other **CheckBoxes** in the window, some of the rows might be read-only. Now, the easiest way I've found to do this is to get the relevant **DataGridRows** and set their `.IsEnabled = false` and changing their background to grey.

This impedes mouse selection of the cells and mouse double-click editing of them as well. As well, using the keyboard directional keys also does not allow entry into the readonly rows either. However, if I edit a cell in the last editable row, finish with <kbd>Enter</kbd> (at which point the edited cell remains apparently selected, but no longer in edit-mode), type in more values and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, the value of the supposedly read-only row is altered.

Below is a "storybook" of what I mean:
[image: Steps taken to edit a theoretically "readonly" row]

Here we have:

1. The user edits an editable cell (in this case, from row 1).
2. The user ends the edit by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The cell is no longer in edit-mode and seemingly remains selected.
3. The user types a value, but instead of editing the apparently selected cell, begins editing the cell in the "readonly" row.
4. By using <kbd>Enter</kbd> once more, the "readonly" cell is modified and the user is free to repeat the process to continue editing other such cells.

I have above used the term "readonly", but in fact I had to define the `DataGridRow.IsEnabled = false`, which might be the cause of this error. However, since **DataGridRow** doesn't contain an `.IsReadOnly` property, this was the only course I could define.

For what its worth, here is the relevant code. You'll notice the binding of the **DataGrid** occurs entirely in the code-behind, but that is because the source of the binding changes according to other parts of the window.

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"
          x:Name="CoordinatesX"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="XColumn" Header="X" Width="50"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**CS**

This is the function which defines which collection should be shown. It can be noted that when EqualToResults (a **CheckBox**) is checked, the entire column is set to **ReadOnly**. When this is the case, the problems presented here do not arise. This may however be simply because the user can't begin to get to an editable row.

```
void ControlBindings()
{
    var resultSections = NProjectProperties.Instance.ResultSections;
    var cable = DataContext as NCable;
    Binding binding;
    if (EqualToResults.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CoordinatesX.ItemsSource = resultSections;
        XColumn.IsReadOnly = true;
        var cStyle = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
        cStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightGray));
        XColumn.CellStyle = cStyle;
        binding = new Binding();
        nSections.Value = resultSections.Count;
    }
    else
    {
        CoordinatesX.ItemsSource = cable.Points;
        XColumn.IsReadOnly = false;
        XColumn.CellStyle = null;
        binding = new Binding("X");
    }
    XColumn.Binding = binding;
}
```

This is the function which sets the necessary rows to `.IsEnabled = false` if another **CheckBox**, EqualSpacing, is checked.

```
void CheckConstraints()
{
    var cable = DataContext as NCable;
    int nPoints = cable.Points.Count;
    if (EqualSpacing.IsChecked == true)
    {
        DataGridRow r;
        for (int i = 1; i < nPoints - 1; i++)
        {
            r = CoordinatesX.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
            if (r == null)
                break;
            r.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            r.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        r = CoordinatesX.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(nPoints - 1) as DataGridRow;
        if (r == null)
            return;
        r.Background = ((nPoints - 1) % 2 == 0 ? Brushes.White : Brushes.AliceBlue);
        r.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to this? Am I doing something wrong?